# Access private pod with git token

Tags: ios, github, cocoapods

How to install a private pod from git using username and token?
Here is what I have tried so far:
included the source into the pod

```
source 'https://cdn.cocoapods.org/‘
source 'https:github.com/your_repo'
target 'app' do
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'private_pod'
end
```

this doesn't work because git don't have access to pod yet

Answer (score 1):

here what work for me:

```
source 'https://cdn.cocoapods.org/‘
source 'https://{git_username}:{git_token}@github.com/your_repo'
target 'app' do
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'private_pod'
end
```

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was addressing the pod directly (without adding the repo as source) and adding an access token (in my case generated in GitLab) to the https-URL.

Example:

```
pod 'the-private-pod', :git => "https://oauth2:YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN_HERE@gitlab.com/xxx/yyy/the-private-pod.git", :tag => '1.2.3'
```